# rails access to other controllers/models when more models are involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, activerecord, model, controller

I have a rails app. There is a user, a task and conversation model as well. Users can assign tasks to each other. A task always belongs to 2 users, one assigner and one executor.

1. On the user show page (and task show page) I would like to have an embedded chat (conversation view), so the 2 users can talk to each other real-time.
2. I want the conversation to be created (same like task, 2 users only) if there is already at least one task assigned between them.
3. I will use the first_or_create method for the conversation model, so if the 2 users already chatted before, then they can continue the previous conversation, so there will be only one conversation between 2 given users.
4. There is no direct connection between task and conversation, except both belongs_to 2 users. The 2 given users will have the same conversation window for all the tasks they have together.

So in one sentence, I wanna display the conversation on the user show page if at least one task exist and then check if the conversation already exists (if does then continue, else create). This involves 3 controllers and 3 models and I'm totally confused about where to put and access to the different methods.

My questions: Where (controller/model, and which one) should I put the if/else statement that checks if there was at least one task assigned between the 2 given user? How to refer to that method when creating/checking the conversation? What params do I need to pass when I try to get to the user show page to be able to be able to check the task situation and display the conversation if needed? What else should I take into account?

Comment: I would have a different controller to handle the chat, and call it in an iframe, passing the relevant user ids and task id as params.  Then you can make a partial or helper to call it, and include this partial/helper wherever you want the chatbox to appear.

Answer (score 0):

> have an embedded chat (conversation view)

This is more than just Rails - you'll have to investigate asynchronous connectivity, the likes of which [Pusher](http://pusher.com) or [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) can deliver (as an *extension* to Rails).

---

> Where (controller/model, and which one) should I put the if/else
>   statement that checks if there was at least one task assigned between
>   the 2 given user?

To make it "real time", you'll have to have a separate `chats` controller which your web socket will continuously ping. The chats can be initiated with an authorization in the chats controller itself, giving you the ability to determine if you should load or refresh a chat.

You'd therefore put it in the *controller*.

*Models* are used to build and clarify data. If you're not building data, there's no need to access the model. The controller is where the logic should go:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :chats #-> @user.chats.first.recipient
end

#app/models/chat.rb
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
   belongs_to :master, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
   belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :recipient_id
end

#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :chat
   #will have to associate users here
end
```

These are the models you should use.

If you have them set up correctly, it will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :chats, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update] #-> url.com/users/:user_id/chats/:id
end

#app/controllers/chats_controller.rb
class ChatsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @user = User.find params[:id]
       if @user.chats.where(recipient: current_user).any?
          # invoke chat here
       else
          # do something else
       end
   end
end
```

---

> How to refer to that method when creating/checking the conversation?

The way to refer to the conversation will be to use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

No not "normal" Ajax, the WebSockets equivalent. I have limited experience with it, but both work in very similar ways (from a developer's perspective):

- JS on your view opens an asynchronous connection to a URL
- The URL responds either as connected or not
- If connected, the websocket stays connected; standard Ajax cuts off

If you use the likes of *pusher*, you'll be able to establish a websocket infrastructure with no overhead on your own part (their servers handle all the connectivity).

You'd have to set up a route (as above) to give you a way to retrieve any data you needed. You'd then set up JS on your page to run *after* document ready.

Once loaded, you'll be able to ping the controller action - it will decide how to handle the request. The logic should be like this:

- JS pings the `chats` controller (similar to above)
- `chats` controller checks existence of "chat" between two users (`show` user and `current_user`
- if exists, pulls data and sends back
- if doesn't exist, creates a new one
- JS takes response and utilizes it in the DOM
- Pusher etc will give you the capacity to update the data in real time

EITHER WAY you basically need to retrieve the "chat" data from either user. If no chat exists, send back a new chat window, or error. If it does exist, send the JSON data.

> What params do I need to pass when I try to get to the user show page to be able to be able to check the task situation and display the conversation if needed?

I don't know how a *task* would come into this; what I do know is that you're sending a request through an asynchronous connection (IE AJAX or Websocks), you'll get all the params you would if you sent a synchronous connection.

Thus, from the example above, you'll be able to see that you could send your ping requests to `url.com/users/:user_id/chats`. `:user_id` will be defined by the `show` action you will be browsing.

Comment: Hi Rich, chat is already done with private_pub gem (faye). It works fine, I used this tut as template: http://bit.ly/1MbrEio. My only problem w/ this solution that you have to click on the button to invoke it, unlike what I mentioned above. My models are the same what you wrote. Only difference is routing. Conversation model (chat as you call) doesn't belong to user resource, as I only use it as partial view in other models' views. I may have to change this one based on you suggestion.  Pls, take a look at this issue, it belongs to this question with different approach: http://bit.ly/1OgesgF

Comment: In regards to the routes, I was only going off what you said: `On the user show page`. Since you have a user show page, you can send the chat request URL through it to get the param of the user you're trying to ping

Comment: Based on the tutorial, can you tell me how I can implement the chat window as rails partial instead of JS? I was thinking of a create_or_first method in the conversation model instead of the current conversation controller solution, and a simple if_task_any method in user/task model that checks if there is any task. I just don't see how I can connect these as I'm not experienced enough.